# Why does a number declared as an implicit type default to integer in C#?

Tags: c#, var, implicit-typing

**Example 1**

```
var test = Byte.MaxValue;
Console.WriteLine(test + " : " + test.GetType().Name);
```

***Result 255 : Byte***

**Example 2**

```
var test = 255;
Console.WriteLine(test + " : " + test.GetType().Name);
```

***Result 255 : Int32***

**Example 3**

```
var test = 10;
Console.WriteLine(test + " : " + test.GetType().Name);
```

***Result 10 : Int32***

**Example 4**

```
var test = 255;
test = Int64.MaxValue;  
Console.WriteLine(test + " : " + test.GetType().Name);
```

***Result : Error :Cannot implicitly convert type long to int***

My question is why does C# default the type to Int32 when using `var`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and can you please add a comment while down voting, it helps me improve. thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C# isn't defaulting to Int32 just when you use var. C# defaults to Int32 when you declare an integer literal without supplying a type hint (as long as the literal fits into an Int32, otherwise it will go to Int64). Since the literal is typed as Int32, the var automatically picks up that type:

> In C#, literal values receive a type from the compiler. You can
>   specify how a numeric literal should be typed by appending a letter to
>   the end of the number. For example, to specify that the value 4.56
>   should be treated as a float, append an "f" or "F" after the number - MSDN

Comment: Unless the literal is too big to fit in a `Int32`.

Answer (score 5):

It's not `var` that defaults to `Int32`, is the integer literal you assign to it.

You can use the suffix `L` to signal that you are writing a `Int64` numeric literal.

Answer (score 3):

`var` is not defaulting to anything. Rather, `var` stands in place of the actual type of the expression that initializes the variable. The question, then, is why is 255 considered `int`? The answer is that without a type hint (f, d, m, U, L, etc.) integer literals are considered to be one of `int`, `uint`, `long`, or `ulong`, depending on which is the smallest type that will fit the number.

Some examples:

```
var i = 255; // var is int
var ui = 4000000000; // var is uint
var l = 5000000000; // var is long
var ul = 9223372036854775808; // var is ulong
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not? `Int32` is used most often I believe. Other numeric types have its suffixes to be added to literal values. `Int32` was chosen to be the one without suffix.

If you want `var` to be other type, use a suffix, i.e.

```
var number = 123f;
```

will be `float`. See [here for more info about numeric literals](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpNumericLiterals.aspx).